# Render all UIViews below in grayscale

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, core-graphics, calayer

In my app, I would like to present a transparent UIView (or layer) which acts as a color filter. So, when this view is presented everything below, it is shown in grayscale.

Is this possible, and if yes how would you go about doing this? I know how to render a UIView specifically in grayscale but this is not what I want to achieve.

Thanks!

Comment: Had you think of set background color for your view and alpha to make it look slightly transparent

Comment: Take a screenshot from your views, convert the image to gray scale, put it there as `UIImageView`. The only viable solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I didn't find any acceptable solution I went and created this myself. 
You can check it out in my [Git repository](https://github.com/freshking/BKFilterView.git). It cannot only filter in grayscale but also sepia, etc. Check out the project, its pretty straight forward.

Any contributions to the project are welcome, there is obviously a lot to add and improve!

[image]

Comment: This is a noob question probably, but how to use it in Obj-C ?

Answer (score 0):

A lot easier than drawing everything with a lot of code:

You could add this view on top. Layout etc. just as every view.

```
let view = UIView()
// with alpha components: modify saturation. Without => alpha 1.0 Gray scale
view.backgroundColor = .white
view.layer.compositingFilter = "hueBlendMode"
view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```